# parBuffer evaluation not giving expected speedup

Tags: multithreading, haskell, concurrency

I have a haskell function I want to evaluate with exact intermediate results:

```
f 0 x = 0
f n x = let tmp = f (n-1) x in
        tmp + (x-tmp^2)/2
```

Because of the (^2) the complexity grows exponentially in n. Since I want to do a plot and the computations for two different x are completely independant, I would have expected nearly optimal speedup from parallel evaluation. My code for this:

```
import Data.Ratio
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

f 0 x = 0
f n x = let tmp = f (n-1) x in
        tmp + (x-tmp^2)/2

main = do
        it <- readLn
        let fn = fromRational . f it 
            values = map fn [0,1%2..10] :: [Double]
            computed = values `using` parBuffer 16 rseq
        mapM_ (putStrLn . show) computed
```

But to my surprise this does not really scale (on my dual core i3 with HT):

```
$ ghc -threaded -O f.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( f.hs, f.o )
Linking f ...
$ time echo 20 | (./f +RTS -N1 > /dev/null)

real    0m4.760s
user    0m4.736s
sys     0m0.016s
$ time echo 20 | (./f +RTS -N2 > /dev/null)

real    0m4.041s
user    0m5.416s
sys     0m2.548s
$ time echo 20 | (./f +RTS -N3 > /dev/null)

real    0m4.884s
user    0m10.936s
sys     0m3.464s
$ time echo 20 | (./f +RTS -N4 > /dev/null)

real    0m5.536s
user    0m17.028s
sys     0m3.888s
```

What am I doing wrong here? It looks like it spends quite some time in locks (sys?) instead of doing useful work.

Comment: It seems you need `parList` then `parBuffer`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that as the overall runtime is relatively small, you're suffering a lot from initial resizing of the heap during garbage collections. You can try making the initial allocation area larger by passing `+RTS -A100M`.

Comment: Thank you, speedup with threads <= cores is now perfect, and remains steady for more threads.

Comment: Also, consider using Threadscope to see what's going on on each of your cores.